# How to build curl with tcp-fastoption

Tags: linux, curl, tcp, build

I have built curl 7.52.1, but I can't use CURLOPT_TCP_FASTOPEN (has added in 7.49)

If I try from command line:
curl --tcp-fastopen -O http://google.com

I get:
curl: (4) A requested feature, protocol or option was not found built-in in this libcurl due to a build-time decision.

I suggest I need enable this option in build, but I don't know how.

Did anybody run into this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer.
My linux(ver 2.6) is too old, it haven't TFO, consequently haven't MSG_FASTOPEN

This define(option) exist on linux 3.6 and higher.
On 3.6-3.12 versions you need to enable this function in kernel.
On 3.13 version and higher this option enabled by default.

For build library on old linux you can write

## define MSG_FASTOPEN 0x20000000

But you don't able to use it